# How to avoid creating a Rect object onDraw

Tags: android, memory, canvas, android-linearlayout, ondraw

In my application I create my LinearLayout class overriding LinearLayout in order to set programmatically borders around it and other graphics on demand (i.e. fill with custom color). The problem is that in the first line of onDraw I have to get layout Rect as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    r = canvas.getClipBounds() ;
```

The problem is that I get the warning:

*Avoid object allocations during draw operations: Use Canvas.getClipBounds(Rect) instead of Canvas.getClipBounds() which allocates a temporary Rect.*

Although I understand that the above code is wasting memory resources, I can not find the way to apply instead *Canvas.getClipBounds(Rect)* to do the same. I would be grateful if someone point at me the way to do this in a more memory friendly way.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your `Rect` when the constructor of your view is called or declare and instantiate it at the same time. E.g.

```
Rect mRect = new Rect();
```

and `onDraw`

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.getClipBounds(mRect) ;
    // read the properties of mRect
```